# trying to understand threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm in doubt, so please help me.

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class class_1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.worker()
        if self.a > 10:
            self.b = True

    def worker(self):
        self.a = self.a + 1
        time.sleep(1)

    def get_a(self):
        return self.a

    def get_b(self):
        return self.b
```

I would like to start instance of a class in a thread (and at some point have several of instances), and pull values from instance(s) to main thread or to separate thread.

something like this:

```
 def run_instance_1():
     global one = class_1
     one.run()

 def pull_1():
     global one
     w = one.get_a()
     z = one.get_b()
     print ('one.a = ' + str(w))
     print ('one.b = ' + str(z))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(name='process 1', target=run_instance_1)
    t2 = threading.Thread(name='process 2', target=pull_1)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

My question is: if I instantiate class in global variable like above, will it really run in a separate thread?  Basic concept for this is to obtain data from "another" thread. Idea for instantiating class in a global variable is to be acessible from any thred. Am I on to something or totaly off?

Comment: Classes don't run, their methods do. If you want to call methods from different threads, better instantiate it first and pass to each thread using `args` argument. Otherwise you assume the order of thread execution, which is not safe.

Comment: @ bereal:  thanks for swift comment. I'm not shure if I understand this. Can You provide simple example?

Comment: You can certainly access global variables from different threads; you really have to be careful, though, because the threads can run in any order and they can easily step over each other. As others have pointed out, your `pull_1` might try to use the `one` variable before anything has been assigned to it, which would be an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share the same object between threads, but instead of using global variables, I'd much rather pass the instance to both threads:

```
def run_instance_1(one):
    one.run()

def pull_1(one):
    w = one.get_a()
    z = one.get_b()
    print ('one.a = ' + str(w))
    print ('one.b = ' + str(z))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    one = class_1()
    t1 = threading.Thread(name='process 1', target=run_instance_1, args=(one,))
    # alternatively: t1 = threading.Thread(target=one.run) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(name='process 2', target=pull_1, args=(one,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

That way you make sure that the instance is created before both threads start and make the functions reusable. Another potential problem is that the class attributes are modified in the thread, and those changes are not atomic. You're highly unlikely to get this in this particular case, but consider using [locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) for shared access to mutable data.

Comment: thanks guys for help, now i have better understanding how this actually works.